# How to use variable in shell command in jenkinsfile

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I've following code from Jenkinsfile, however the pipeline fails because the shell command remains incomplete as the variable can't be imported into the shell command.

```
environment{
        S3_URL = "S3://samplebucket/code.zip"
}

steps 
{
   script
   {
      withAWS(role: "${AWS_ARN}", externalId: "${EXT_ID}", region: "${AWS_REGION}"){
         sh '''
         export PATH="$PATH:/root/.dotnet/tools"
         cd code
         dotnet lambda deploy-function
         cd bin/Release/net6.0
         aws s3 cp code.zip '''${S3_URL}''' //<----- Here is the problem
         '''
   }
}
```

I've tried multiple ways to fetch the variable `S3_URL` in the `sh ''' ... '''` block but it always turn out to be blank, consequently an error.

Answer (score 1):

The environment value should be in "" like this `S3_URL = "S3://samplebucket/code.zip"`

I just tried the way you are trying

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    environment{
      S3_URL = "S3://samplebucket/code.zip"
    }
    stages {
        stage("Test"){
            steps {
                script {
                    sh '''
                    echo ${S3_URL}
                    '''
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Just remove the `''''''` around the `'''${S3_URL}'''` and use only `${S3_URL}` it should be like this

`aws s3 cp code.zip ${S3_URL}`

Comment: Thanks Dashrath for the inputs, that works, however have another question on the same lines. I see that if it's not an environment variable, then the solution that you gave doesn't work, the empty value is returned in the shell command, any suggestions?